# Retrieve text from an element and insert it somewhere else

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get the text from between the "p" tags and put it in an other element, like this:

before:

```
<div id="Text">
 <p>$1,200.00</p>
</div>

<div id="putText">
 <p></p>
</div>
```

after:

```
<div id="Text">
 <p>$1,200.00</p>
</div>


<div id="putText">
 <p>$1,200.00</p>
</div>
```

Anyone know of a Javascript that can do this?

Comment: The Javascript in any mainstream browser can do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below function copies the contents of the first paragraph under an element with ID `ID` to a paragraph under another element with ID `putID`.

```
function copyContents(id) {
    var source = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    var target = document.getElementById("put" + id).getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    target.innerHTML = source.innerHTML;
}
copyContents("Text");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use following jQuery code

```
$('#putText p').html($('#Text p').html());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chamika Sandamal, but I can't use jQuery in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery at your disposal, it's fairly easy - something like this should work:

```
$('#putText>p').text($('#Text>p').text())
```

If you don't, then you'll have to resort to some DOM manipulation - the same stuff jQuery does behind the scenes, only you need to code it up yourself.

Comment: I can't use jQuery, I'm using Lekensteyn code now (above) it doesn't need jQuery. Thanks for your reply :)